# Class property still gets applied after removing it via jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a horizontal navigation bar with one dropdown menu. On big screens without touch, the dropdown opens on :hover. On screens with touch, it opens on click. In both cases, the dropdown-content has a display property of 'absolute', while its container is set to 'relative'.

On smaller screens (< 1220px), a single menu icon appears instead of the text links I use for my horizontal nav bar. When clicked, the nav menu opens vertically. For this, the dropdown-content gets a display property of 'static'.

The problem is that on screens bigger than 1220px, it still applies 'static' to the navigation bar which makes the content "jump".

I tried different parent-child selectors and suggestions from other posts, but I can't get them to work for me. What am I doing wrong?

Here's my HTML:

```
<nav id="main-nav">
          <div class="burger-nav"></div>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <div class="dropdown">
              <li class="dropbtn">gallery</li>
              <div class="dropdown-content">
                <li><a href="galerie1.html">gallery 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="galerie-2.html">gallery 2</a></li>
              </div>
            </div>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
```

CSS:

```
/* container for the dropdown menu */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* dropdown menu items */
 .dropdown-content {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

/* dropdown items show on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  opacity: 1;
}

/*mobile & touch */
/* set positions */
.static {
  position: static;
}
.position-fixed {
  position: fixed;
}

/* show dropdown items on click */
.visible {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

jQuery:

```
  $(window).on('resize', function() {
    //always collapse dropdown on screen resize
    $(".dropdown-content").removeClass("visible");
    $(".dropdown-content").removeClass("static");
  });

  //---------toggle dropdown menu on touch screens---------
    $(".dropbtn").on("click", function() {
      $(".dropdown-content").toggleClass("visible");

      if($(window).width() > "1220px") {
        $(".dropdown-content").removeClass("static");
      } else {
        $(".dropdown-content").toggleClass("static");
      }
    });
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. The only things that should be child elements of `<ul>` are `<li>` elements.

Comment: Also your `.width()` comparison won't work. The string `"5px"` is `>` than `"1220px"` when you compare as strings. Seems like you could do this with CSS media queries anyway.

Comment: @Pointy `width()` actually returns number making the string comparison invalid anyway

Comment: @charlietfl yea I couldn't remember offhand but that makes sense

Comment: Thank you both for your hints. I changed my HTML code into <ul> and <li> elements only. I'm also trying media queries now. I considered it before but wasn't sure how/if I can make something like an "on click" event with CSS only, but I think I'm figuring something out.
The " around the 1220px just downright escaped me, so thanks for pointing that out as well!